# Run a python script in a webpage

Tags: python

I have a python script saved in my local.The script basically takes a csv file as input and runs it from my local.

So now I want to do the same thing but from a webpage so that it becomes more user friendly.I want to make a webpage where it takes a csv file as input and runs the script after I click a button.Please help me with ideas on how to do this.

Comment: Check out Flask http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/

Comment: Use Bottle or Flask for a very simple page doing what you want. Use Django if you plan to build a bigger website later